# How to use both DigitalClock and TextClock for android devices from API level 8 to 19?

Tags: android

I'm making the application for devices from API level 8 to 19, that contains clock. I tried to  put the DigitalClock to layout. And I get message from Eclipse that this class deprecated since API level 17, recommended to use TextClock. But when I put TextClock, I get error message, because min level is 8. How to solve this problem? Should I build two different applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option #1: Use `DigitalClock` in `res/layout/` files and `TextClock` in `res/layout-v17/` files. In your Java code that manipulates the clocks, see which clock implementation that you get for your widget ID and branch accordingly.

Option #2: Try to backport `TextClock` by [using its source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextClock.java), so you can create your own version that works back to older API levels.

Option #3: Just use `DigitalClock` and hope that, while it is deprecated, that Google will still support it.

Option #4: Use neither class and create your own clock implementation.