# Why is the Digital clock showing the seconds too in Android ICS version but not in Kitkat version?

Tags: android

I am using the `digital clock` in my application. (I know it is `depricated` but according to the CommonsWare option#3 in [How to use both DigitalClock and TextClock for android devices from API level 8 to 19?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340173/how-to-use-both-digitalclock-and-textclock-for-android-devices-from-api-level-8) , I am hoping the google will continue to support the Digital clock for a few more versions).

But the `digital clock` is showing different text in `ICS` vs `Kitkat`. In `ICS`, it is showing seconds too which is looking ugly in my layout. So is there a way to change the format of time to show only hours and minutes. In the documentation, it is mentioned that it will show seconds, but is there any way around that ?

Comment: In the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html) for `DigitalClock` it says "Like AnalogClock, but digital. Shows seconds." So I'm surprised that it doesn't show seconds.

Comment: Have you solved this?